# Matplotlib different color base on values of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I managed a Dataframe in this way to make a plot with Matplotlib:

```
bigdata = dataM.append(pos, ignore_index=True)
bigdata= bigdata.set_index(['index'], inplace=False)
```

and I have this output :

```
            Value
index   
2020-01-09  90.000000
2020-01-10  96.000000
2020-01-11  98.000000
2020-01-12  98.000000
2020-01-13  100.000000
2020-01-14  92.000000
```

and I made this graph

[image]

I wish to use 2 different colors with 2 different legends in this way ad example

Blue color for data(called before)

```
2020-01-09  90.000000
2020-01-10  96.000000
2020-01-11  98.000000
```

And red for data (called new)

```
2020-01-09  90.000000
2020-01-10  96.000000
2020-01-11  98.000000
```

I saw some solution but is more articulate. 
Can I do a sort of bigdata[bigdata.index > "2020-01-11"] and set a color red in easy way?

Thanks,

***Edit***
After @Quang Hoang solution my graph is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can draw twice:

```
ax = df[:'2020-01-11'].plot(y='Value', c='b', label='early')
df['2020-01-11':].plot(y='Value', c='r', label='late', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried to apply your solution, but i have problem with the graph. I will edit the question